# Is the following usage of the word "suggest" correct/common?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

> Sharing the first hours of the day with someone **suggests** you want to
>   spend the rest of your life with that person.

Is it correct/common to use the word like this? Does it sound weird? If so, what's a more appropriate alternative (aside of *mean*)?

Comment: What exactly makes you think it could be weird of anything? If *suggests* is what is intended to be said, then *suggests* is the word. There could be any number of alternatives depending on what is meant to be stated.

Comment: Have you consulted a dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct usage.  I would add the word "that", though.

> ... suggests that you want ...